# On the calculation of work done to move a particle between two points

Tags: classical-mechanics

**Context:**

In the context of classical mechanics (e.g. the treatment in Goldstein's classic book, ch. 1), we start with the knowledge that force and momentum are related by $\textbf{F}=\dot{\textbf{p}}=m\dot{\textbf{v}}$. Then, we say that the work done by the extrernal force $\textbf{F}$ upon a particle in going from point 1 to point 2 is, by definition, given by:

$W_{12}=\int\limits^{2}_{1}\textbf{F}\cdot d\textbf{s}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $          (eq.1)

And then this is usually reduced by a few steps to give the final scalar result, as follows:

$W_{12}=\int\limits^{2}_{1}\textbf{F}\cdot d\textbf{s}=m\int\limits^{2}_{1}\frac{d\textbf{v}}{dt}\cdot \textbf{v} dt=\frac{m}{2}\int\limits^{2}_{1}\frac{d}{dt}(v^{2})dt=\frac{m}{2}(v_{2}^{2}-v_{1}^{2})\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $       (eq.2)

**The question:**

From (eq.1), it is clear to us that the assumption is that the particle may be moving along an arbitrary (e.g. curved) path between the two points 1 and 2, and that the length (displacement) element along this path may not be parallel to the applied force $\textbf{F}$. So, the vectors $\textbf{F}$ and $d\textbf{s}$ may be pointing in different directions at each point along the path. This is clearly implied by the dot product. Also, it is clear that the movement velocity $\textbf{v}$ vector is confined to the same direction as the displacement element ($d\textbf{s}$) at each point along the path, and not along $\textbf{F}$, so we can write $d\textbf{s}=\textbf{v}dt$. Up to this point, it makes sense to me.

But then how come we replace $\textbf{F}$ with a $m\dot{\textbf{v}}$ (containing the same velocity vector in $d\textbf{s}=\textbf{v}dt$), as if the force $\textbf{F}$ is always parallel to the displacement?  One could initially argue that the acceleration vector ($\dot{\textbf{v}}$) doesn't have to have the same direction as the velocity vector $\textbf{v}$ at each point, but that is refuted in the last two steps in (eq.2) above, when they are considered parallel and a scalar is finally produced. Why was the force $\textbf{F}$ substituted in that manner, as if it were actually along the path direction, making the original dot product meaningless? Is there an implicit assumption or misinterpretation that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what  you are missing is that d/dt(v^2) really does equal the dot product between the vectors v and dv/dt.  So F and dv/dt do not have to point along v, and the theorem still holds.

Comment: Could you please show how their dot product actually result in the the scalar d/dt(v^2), if they are not assumed parallel?

Comment: It is true because d/dt(v^2) is related to the change in the magnitude of velocity, and the magnitude of velocity is only changed by the component of  acceleration that is along that velocity, not perpendicular.  Consider the opposite case where the acceleration is entirely perpendicular to the velocity, like the orbit of Earth or the Lorentz force in a magnetic field.   Is it not clear that those have d/dt(v^2)=0?

Comment: (1/2): The physical meaning is clear, and I understand it. However, I am talking about the mathematical derivation here. Say that $d/dt(\textbf{v})=\textbf{a}$ (another vector), which is not necessarily parallel to $\textbf{v}$, then their dot product is $\textbf{a}\cdot\textbf{v}=\alpha |\textbf{v}| |\textbf{a}|$ (where $\alpha\in[0,1]$ is cosine the angle between them). Now, to put $\alpha |\textbf{v}| |\textbf{z}|$ equal to $|\textbf{v}|d/dt(|\textbf{v}|)=0.5\ d/dt(v^2)$ would imply one of two things:

Comment: (2/2): (continued)... (1) either that we took $\alpha=1$ (force and velocity in same direction) and $|d/dt(\textbf{v})|=d/dt(|\textbf{v}|)$; or (2) that $|d/dt(\textbf{v})|=(1/\alpha)d/dt(|\textbf{v}|)$. Can you help correcting or explaining this?

Comment: It is a mathematical identity that v dot dv/dt equals 1/2 d/dt(v^2).  You can prove this in Cartesian coordinates, for example, just write out v^2 in those coordinates (i.e., the Pythagorean theorem) and take its time derivative.  Or write v^2 = v dot v and take that time derivative.  All you need is d/dt(A dot B) = dA/dt dot B + A dot d/dt B.